# Getting linux to buffer /dev/random

Tags: linux, random, buffer, daemon, entropy

I need a reasonable supply of high-quality random data for an application I'm writing. Linux provides the /dev/random file for this purpose which is ideal; however, because my server is a single-service virtual machine, it has very limited sources of entropy, meaning /dev/random quickly becomes exhausted.

I've noticed that if I read from /dev/random, I will only get 16 or so random bytes before the device blocks while it waits for more entropy:

```
[duke@poopz ~]# hexdump /dev/random
0000000 f4d3 8e1e 447a e0e3 d937 a595 1df9 d6c5
<process blocks...>
```

If I terminate this process, go away for an hour and repeat the command, again only 16 or so bytes of random data are produced.

**However** - if instead I leave the command running for the same amount of time, much, much more random data are collected. I assume from this that over the course of a given timeperiod, the system produces plenty of entropy, but Linux only utilises it if you are actually reading from /dev/random, and discards it if you are not. If this is the case, my question is:

**Is it possible to configure Linux to buffer /dev/random so that reading from it yields much larger bursts of high-quality random data?**

It wouldn't be difficult for me to buffer /dev/random as part of my program but I feel doing this at a system level would be more elegant. I also wonder if having Linux buffer its random data in memory would have security implications.

Comment: AFAIK, entropy is not (entirely) discarded, when the entropy is high enough, the kernel takes 1 in 4096 input samples and mixes that into its entropy pool.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need an [entropy deamon](http://www.vanheusden.com/te/) that feeds the entropy pool from other sources.

Comment: I've just installed that and it does seem to cause more rapid replenishment of /dev/random, which is good. However, /dev/random still exhibits the same behaviour: If I leave it for ten minutes and then read from it, only 16 or so bytes are produced. But if I leave it reading /dev/random constantly for the same period of time, many kilobytes of random data can be retrieved. Clearly, the system has a plentiful supply of randomness already; so wouldn't it be nice if Linux would save all that data up in a buffer for when I need it, rather than throwing it away?

Comment: Yes, I think that's how it works. I don't think they want to buffer a lot of data in the kernel. I suppose a deamon that reads it periodically and keeps a larger buffer would work.

Comment: This is the kind of buffering daemon I need :D But does it exist..?

Answer (score 1):

Use /dev/urandom.

> A counterpart to /dev/random is
>   /dev/urandom ("unlocked"/non-blocking
>   random source[4]) which reuses the
>   internal pool to produce more
>   pseudo-random bits. This means that
>   the call will not block, but the
>   output may contain less entropy than
>   the corresponding read from
>   /dev/random. While it is still
>   intended as a pseudorandom number
>   generator suitable for most
>   cryptographic purposes, it is not
>   recommended for the generation of
>   long-term cryptographic keys.

Comment: Yes, I'd look at /dev/urandom but decided against it as I need high-quality randomness.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got, or can you buy, a Linux-compatible hardware random number generator? That could be a solution to your underlying problem. See http://www.linuxcertified.com/hw_random.html

Comment: Yes this would be ideal, I've seen a few USB entropy generator dongles, and I've heard you can also use the noise from an audio input device. However this particular system is just a cheap VM on the other side of the world. From my tests it does actually produce enough entropy for my application over time - but it does not collect it, so a buffer would seem like the cheapest solution.