# Not enough entropy to support /dev/random in docker containers running in boot2docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker

Running out of entropy in virtualized Linux systems seems to be a common problem (e.g. [/dev/random Extremely Slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819359/dev-random-extremely-slow), [Getting linux to buffer /dev/random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633877/getting-linux-to-buffer-dev-random)). Despite of using a hardware random number generator (HRNG) the use of a an entropy gathering daemon like [HAVEGED](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/index.html) is often suggested. However an entropy gathering daemon (EGD) cannot be run inside a Docker container, it must be provided by the host.

Using an EGD works fine for docker hosts based on linux distributions like Ubuntu, RHEL, etc. Getting such a daemon to work inside boot2docker - which is based on Tiny Core Linux (TCL) - seems to be another story. Although TCL has a extension mechanism, an extension for an entropy gathering daemon [doesn't seem to be available](http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/index.php?topic=15650.0).

So an EGD seems like a proper solution for running docker containers in a (production) hosting environment, but how to solve it for development/testing in boot2docker?

Since running an EGD in boot2docker seemed too difficult, I thought about simply using /dev/urandom instead of /dev/random. Using /dev/urandom is a litte less secure, but still fine for most applications which are not generating long-term cryptographic keys. At least it should be fine for development/testing inside boot2docker.

Comment: openssl user `urandom`. What are you doing that requires more?

Comment: Some Java cryptographic providers relay on /dev/random (e.g. for secure random number generation).

Comment: I agree you can't always control that. In any case, here you've got some additional info about java `SecureRandom` vs `/dev/[u]random` - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4705093

Answer (score 60):

I just realized, that it is simple as mounting /dev/urandom from the host as /dev/random into the container:

```
$ docker run -v /dev/urandom:/dev/random ...
```

The result is as expected:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v /dev/urandom:/dev/random ubuntu dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/null bs=1 count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1024 bytes (1.0 kB) copied, 0.00223239 s, 459 kB/s
```

At least I know how to build my own boot2docker images now ;-)

Comment: The impacts on security by using /dev/urandom instead of /dev/random on development machines should be quite limited.

Comment: "Fact: /dev/urandom is the preferred source of cryptographic randomness on UNIX-like systems." http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/

Comment: What about cross-platform compatibility, i.e. for those poor souls running Windows?

Comment: I've tried a lot of the `rng-tools`/`haveged` suggestions and this is the only one that worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Claudiu docker-toolbox for Windows still runs on linux, and docker for Windows 10+ runs on the linux subsystem (if I understood correctly), so that should still work?

Comment: This is the same as running `ln -s /dev/urandom /dev/random` inside the container. /dev/random and /dev/urandom are always mapped to host.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30577161/675721) for more info

Answer (score 17):

The most elegant solution I've found is running Haveged in separate container:

```
docker pull harbur/haveged
docker run --privileged -d harbur/haveged
```

Check whether enough entropy available:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
2066
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to install the **rng-tools** package and map it to use the /dev/urandom

```
  yum install rng-tools
  rngd -r /dev/urandom
```

With this I didn't need to map any volume in the docker container.

Comment: This gives me this message: `unable to adjust write_wakeup_threshold: Read-only file system`

Comment: Run it on the docker host, not in the container.

Answer (score 3):

Since I didn't like to modify my Docker containers for development/testing I tried to modify the boot2docker image. Luckily, the boot2docker image is build with Docker and can be easily [extended](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/BUILD.md#making-your-own-customised-boot2docker-iso). So I've set up my own Docker build [boot2docker-urandom](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/mbonato/boot2docker-urandom/). It extends the standard boot2docker image with a udev rule found [here](https://superuser.com/a/563866).

Building your own boot2docker.iso image is simple as

```
$ docker run --rm mbonato/boot2docker-urandom > boot2docker.iso
```

To replace the standard boot2docker.iso that comes with boot2docker you need to:

```
$ boot2docker stop
$ boot2docker delete
$ mv boot2docker.iso ~/.boot2docker/
$ boot2docker init
$ boot2docker up
```

**Limitations**, from inside a Docker container /dev/random still blocks. Most likely, because the Docker containers do not use /dev/random of the host directly, but use the corresponding kernel device - which still blocks.

Answer (score 3):

if you have this problem in a docker container created from a self-built image that runs a java app (e.g. created `FROM tomcat:alpine`) and don't have access to the host (e.g. on a managed k8s cluster), you can add the following command to your dockerfile to use non-blocking seeding of `SecureRandom`:

```
RUN sed -i.bak \
  -e "s/securerandom.source=file:\/dev\/random/securerandom.source=file:\/dev\/urandom/g" \
  -e "s/securerandom.strongAlgorithms=NativePRNGBlocking/securerandom.strongAlgorithms=NativePRNG/g" \
  $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.security
```

the two regex expressions replace `file:/dev/random` by `file:/dev/urandom` and `NativePRNGBlocking` by `NativePRNG` in the file `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.security` which causes tomcat to startup reasonably fast on a vm. i haven't checked whether this works also on non alpine-based openjdk images, but if the `sed` command fails, just check the location of the file `java.security` inside the container and adapt the path accordingly.

***note:*** in jdk11 the path has changed to `$JAVA_HOME/conf/security/java.security`

Comment: too base this technique does not work with openjdk11 as the java.security file does not exist.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano: I use `openjdk` from https://adoptopenjdk.net (for my own use currently Java8, but for an experiment today Jdk11). After downloading and extracting Jdk11 from this site, I ran the command `$ grep -r securerandom *`, which gave me the path `conf/security/java.security` (relative path below the Jdk home directory). I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm talking specifically about the `openjdk:11-slim` image from docker hub but hopefully it is in the same spot as you said

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano: just in case: enter an `openjdk:11-slim`-container as follows: `$ docker run --rm -it openjdk:11-slim bash`, then `$ cd /` (just to make sure you are in the root directory), then `$ grep -r securerandom *` which gives here: `etc/java-11-openjdk/security/java.security` (the search takes a while, but you can stop it using Ctrl+C, then exit using Ctrl+D). this would most likely work also in other containers based on images that contains a jvm.

Answer (score 2):

[Alpine Linux](http://alpinelinux.org/) may be a better choice for a lightweight `docker` host. Alpine `LXC` & `docker` images are only 5mb (versus 27mb for `boot2docker`)

I use `haveged` on [Alpine](http://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?package=haveged&repo=all&arch=x86) for `LXC` guests & on Debian for `docker` guests. It gives enough entropy to generate `gpg` / `ssh` keys & `openssl` certificates in containers. [Alpine now has an official `docker` repo](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/library/alpine/).

Alternatively build a `haveged` package for Tiny Core - there is a [package build system](https://code.google.com/p/tc-ext-tools/wiki/Introduction) available.