# How to use GnuPG inside Docker containers, as it is missing entropy?

Tags: docker, gnupg, entropy, openpgp

I need to dockerize an apt repository. The packages in it need to be signed, which is currently done by 
`aptly publish snapshot -distribution="stable" -gpg-key="<key id>" my-snapshot`

Before that a key needs to be created using `gpg --gen-key`.

But this way the private key will be crated inside the docker image, which doesn't seem to be a good practice. Besides, id doesn't even work; running `gpg --gen-key --batch <gpg.in` gets stuck:

```
Not enough random bytes available.  Please do some other work to give
the OS a chance to collect more entropy! (Need 284 more bytes)
```

I don't know if it's even possible to generate a gpg key inside a docker container, and even if it is, it may not be a good idea.

Is there a way to sign the contents of the repo by an external key?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Missing Entropy

Docker does *not* provide a virtual `/dev/[u]random` devices. If you haven't got enough entropy in the container, you haven't got enough entropy on the host.

Check the contents of `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`, they should be pretty much the same on both the Docker host and container (if the number is slightly different, it just changes very frequently, otherwise recheck a few times).

Possible reasons:

- Running the docker host in a virtual machine, for example because of `boot2docker` or a self-constructed virtual machine. Just make sure to get more entropy inside your virtual machine, `havegd` is a very easy solution for a developer machine, but might not be appropriate for production.
- Another container/application is using up all entropy. Realize which one and interrupt/terminate it, or generate more entropy.
- You're generally not having enough entropy. Do some work (mouse/keyboard movements, (hard) disk I/O).

### Externally Generating a Key Pair

Anyway, it might be more reasonable to generate a key on a real machine, and only move a (private) *subkey* to the server. This way, you can exchange the subkey every now and then (and in case it was compromised). Read [What is a good general purpose GnuPG key setup?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31598/19837) for an introduction to different things to consider while setting up OpenPGP keys.

While building the Docker image, use `COPY` to get the file into the machine, and then `gpg --import` it in the Dockerfile. Afterwards, it is available exactly the same way it would've been if you generated it inside the container using `gpg --gen-key`.

Comment: I imported the key generated on host, used it to sing the repo and deleted .gnupg directory after singing the repo.

Comment: When deleting it, be aware of the different layers and that the private key might not _actually_ be deleted, but just hidden.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to speed the entropy generation greatly by pinging some websites while connected to the docker container where the `gpg` key was being generated.

```
$ docker exec -it blimp_mailpilekermit_1 bash
mailpile@mailpile-kermit:~$ ping google.com &
mailpile@mailpile-kermit:~$ ping cloudfleet.io &
mailpile@mailpile-kermit:~$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
757
```

This got the `gpg` process to finish generating a 2048 bit key relatively quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Generate the key outside of `docker build`, inside the same directory tree as your `Dockerfile`. Then you can `ADD` the key to the image and it'll be available to `aptly`. Remember that this image now contains a private GPG key, so it needs to be kept just as private as you would that key.

If you want to use the key inside a running container (rather than while building an image), use the `-v` flag to mount the key file inside the image. (This allows you to publish your image without publishing your private key.

Answer (score 0):

Flood pinging the external interface (from another host) will also add entropy to the pool.

eg. ping -f $EXTERNALIP

Need to be root, and best not to do this across a network you care about.