# is it possible to reset urandom when starting docker?

Tags: docker, cryptography

I have a need to start docker with a crypto secure random number generator. With all the default settings I repeat key generations with every restart. Is there something I can do to reset urandom (I presume) by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `/dev/urandom` as a crypto secure random number generator, use `/dev/random` instead. This should already be linked with `/dev/random` on the container host. From [`man urandom`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/urandom):

> If you are unsure about whether you should use /dev/random or /dev/urandom, then probably you want to use the latter. As a general rule, /dev/urandom should be used for everything **except long-lived GPG/SSL/SSH keys**.

If you need a globally seeded `/dev/urandom` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26024403/1643939). In essence you can just link in the host's `/dev/urandom` to the container which should be impervious to container restarts. But again, do not use this for crypto.