# Change Java "SecureRandom" in Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, tomcat7, dockerfile

I am using the docker image of tomcat with jre8,
I have to change an option inside the java environment, it is possible to do it after the container is running, ssh to it and change

> securerandom.source=file:/dev/random

to

> securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom

inside

> root@112ecdd0b71f:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/java.security

However, I want to do it automatically on before the container is starting up, because the current setting takes a lot of time to the tomcat to start-up.

Comment: The slow startup might be caused by lack of entropy. You might want to mount actual host /dev/random to you image. Check this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26024403/4990550.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options for these kind of changes.

1. Create a new image and override the JVM system property.

   You would generally create a new `Dockerfile` based on the original one you used and make your changes there. You could use `JAVA_OPTS` or `CATALINA_OPTS` like:

   ```
   FROM tomcat:8-jre8
   ENV CATALINA_OPTS -Dsecurerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom
   ```
2. Set the JVM system property at runtime in the existing image.

   This would be done using `docker run`. Just pass `-e CATALINA_OPTS="-Dsecurerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom"`. Something like:

   ```
   docker run -e CATALINA_OPTS="-Dsecurerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom" tomcat:8-jre8
   ```
3. Create a new image and change the file (not recommended).

   You can also create a new image and just make the change that you were originally making (though, I don't really like changing files inside an image when they don't need to).

   ```
   FROM tomcat:8-jre8
   RUN sed -i 's/file:\/dev\/random/file:\/dev\/urandom/' /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/java.security
   ```