# SecureRandom is not working as expected in docker adoptopenjdk-tomcat image

Tags: java, docker, tomcat9, adoptopenjdk, secure-random

I am using docker image of tomcat to run the application. The image details are:
**tomcat:9.0.45-jdk11-adoptopenjdk-hotspot**.

When I run the application on my local machine where I have **jdk11-adoptopenjdk** installed the application working fine but same I deployed into the container it starts failing.

I found the issue in code where I am creating a list of integers using SecureRandom class. Here is the code:

> SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong().ints(capacity, minNumber,
> maxNumber).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

When the code executes this line, it stuck there only.

Just wanted to  know, is there any issue while using SecureRandom with docker etc becuase I gone through few below links and what I understand that it refers OS level mechanisms. [Link](https://tersesystems.com/blog/2015/12/17/the-right-way-to-use-securerandom/#:%7E:text=SHA1PRNG%20(Initial%20seeding%20is%20currently,()%20use%20%2Fdev%2Frandom))

Comment: A Docker container has very few entropy (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26021181/11748454)). Probably that's why it gets _"stuck"_.

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz .. thanks for the help.